Zap proxy fails to communicate with services on HTTPS?
I run zap proxy as a service in k8s using the below command:
      command: [ "zap.sh" ]
      args: [ "-daemon", "-port", "9090",  "-config", "api.disablekey=true", "-config", "api.addrs.addr.name=.*", "-config", "api.addrs.addr.regex=true", "-config", "view.mode=attack","-host","0.0.0.0", "-config","network.localServers.mainProxy.behindNat=true","-config", "network.connection.timeOutInSecs=120" , "-config", "network.httpState.timeoutInSecs=120","-silent"]

and this Dockerfile:
FROM softwaresecurityproject/zap-bare

ENV HUD=false
ENV API_DISABLEKEY=true
ENV ZAP_AUTO_UPDATE=false
ENV ZAP_PORT = 9090


EXPOSE 9090
 

Although, it works well when i call any service on http, I get a http 504 error when I call https://my-service.com/v1/my-endpoint which is working on https and the exact error is:

Failed to read https:https://my-service.com/v1/my-endpoint within 20 seconds, check to see if the site is available and if so consider adjusting ZAP's read time out in the Connection options panel.

Please note, as I need to communicate with both http and https protocols, I decided to turn off the HUD because it converts http protocol to https.
Update: when, I try to hit the target api using below curl command:
curl https://my-service.com/v1/my-endpoint

I get no error and no response

That is somewhat surprising. The HUD defaults to off in daemon mode.
I'm not sure where you got the ENV HUD=false line from - that wont have any effect.
Have you checked that you can access the target from the docker image, e.g. using curl?

chatGPT is, once again, wrong. Its not good with details :P
Re curl, I'm not asking you to proxy through ZAP, just access the target, e.g. curl https://my-service.com/v1/my-endpoint

Again sorry, @SimonBennetts i had a mistake in my curl command. i just updated my question. can you please double check it ?

You have a networking problem, not a ZAP problem.
If other programs like curl cant access your target site then its not just ZAP, its a lower level problem.
